# Multipart form-data example using Undertow

Tags: java, undertow

I'm trying to upload a text file from a html form.

Is there any example on how to get the text-file from the `HttpHandler`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once used the following code:

```
    Builder builder = FormParserFactory.builder();

    final FormDataParser formDataParser = builder.build().createParser(exchange);
    if (formDataParser != null) {
        exchange.startBlocking();
        FormData formData = formDataParser.parseBlocking();

        for (String data : formData) {
            for (FormData.FormValue formValue : formData.get(data)) {
                if (formValue.isFile()) {
                    // process file here: formValue.getFile();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Based on: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in **EagerFormParsingHandler** and chain your handler, as in the example below. This handler will parse the request and store the multi-part file(s) to your "java.io.tmpdir" system property defined directory (by default, but is configurable). In your handle, you can find the file and process it as you want. Additionally, **EagerFormParsingHandler** adds a listener in order to delete any created files from your file system, as soon as the exchange completes.

```
    HttpHandler multipartProcessorHandler = (exchange) -> {
        FormData attachment = exchange.getAttachment(FormDataParser.FORM_DATA);
        FormData.FormValue fileValue = attachment.get("file").getFirst();
        Path file = fileValue.getPath();
    };

    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(
            new EagerFormParsingHandler(
                FormParserFactory.builder()
                    .addParsers(new MultiPartParserDefinition())
                    .build()
            ).setNext(multipartProcessorHandler)
        )
        .build();
    server.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
public class HttpServer{

    public void start() throws IOException{

        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
            .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    // Parses HTTP POST form data and passes it to a handler asynchronously 
                    FormDataParser parser = FormParserFactory.builder().build().createParser(exchange);
                    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
                    parser.parse(handler);
                }
            }).build();

        server.start();

    }

    private class MyHandler implements HttpHandler{
        @Override
        public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
            // Form data is stored here
            FormData formData = exchange.getAttachment(FormDataParser.FORM_DATA);
            // Iterate through form data
            for (String data : formData) {
                for (FormData.FormValue formValue : formData.get(data)) {
                    if (formValue.isFileItem()) {
                        // Process file here
                        File uploadedFile = formValue.getFileItem().getFile().toFile();
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the documentation:

> **void parse(HttpHandler next)
>       throws Exception**
>
> Parse the form data asynchronously. If all the data cannot be read
>   immediately then a read listener will be registered, and the data will
>   be parsed by the read thread.  When this method completes the handler
>   will be invoked, and the data will be attached under FORM_DATA.
>
> The method can either invoke the next handler directly, or may
>   delegate to the IO thread to perform the parsing.